# get selected="selected" text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, gettext

i have this html code, how can i get the text which has selected="selected" option with jquery ?

```
   <option selected="selected" value="1">m</option>
<option value="2">n</option>
<option value="3">o</option>
<option selected="selected" value="4">p</option>
<option value="5">q</option>
<option value="6">r</option>
<option value="7">s</option>
<option selected="selected" value="8">t</option>
<option value="9">u</option>
<option value="10">v</option>
```

thanks

Comment: [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can put them in an array

```
var arr = $('option:selected').map(function(){ return $(this).text() }).get();
// arr[0] = 1
// arr[1] = 4
// arr[2] = 8
```

I suppose it's multi select.

Comment: Bear in mind that the attribute-equals selector won't match any options selected by the user following page-load.

Comment: it is simple : 

    var selected=$( "#myselectId option:selected" ).text();